# How to access members of container class with same name? scala

Tags: scala

I have something like this:

```
abstract class HaveData{
  val data:String
}
class HD1 extends HaveData{
  val data = "HD1 data"
}
class HD2 extends HaveData{
  val data = "HD2 data"
  object InnerHD extends HD1{
    def prt = println(data)
  }
}
```

I want to print "HD2 data" not "HD1 data", how to do that?

I may turn InnerHD to a class and provide data as a param but is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of situations you can use a [***self-type***](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html), for this specific problem, you do not need to add a different type.

```
abstract class HaveData {
  def data: String
}
class HD1 extends HaveData {
  override val data = "HD1 data"
}
class HD2 extends HaveData { self => // Alias to this in the HD2 level.
  override val data = "HD2 data"
  object InnerHD extends HD1 {
    def prt(): Unit = {
      println(self.data)
    }
  }
}

(new HD2).InnerHD.prt()
// HD2 data
```

Comment: Why did you add the unnecessary `override` and `{` `}` to the original code?

Comment: @Tim style, nothing more, nothing less. If you believe it could cause confusion, feel free to edit it :)

Comment: Thank you! I'm still trying to figure it out but thank you!

Comment: So 'self =>' should be before 'data' definition or wherever in the HD2 body?

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov it does has to be the first statement.

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov which version of **Scala** do you have?

Comment: Sorry, needed time to find it, 2.11.12

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov I checked with different versions _(from 2.10 to 2.13)_, and it worked on all of them. Check it for yourself in this [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/UYZng1rgTB2njdudtobB9A).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
def prt = println(HD2.this.data)
```

Comment: This seems as even better solution, should I reaccept this one?

Comment: Your choice, I wouldn't since the other answer is not really worse and significantly earlier.